# Why aren't my arguments being passed to the parameters?

Tags: python

Project dealing with functions and making a main function.

Control the rest of the functions.

```
wall = 112
paint = 1
work = 8
premier = 20.50
generic = 10.75
labor_c = 12.75

print('Welcome to A&PM Painting Co. How may we help you today?''\n')
def paint_job():
    space = float(input('What is the measurement of the area' +\
                       ' you want painted? '))
    gallon(space)
    labor()
    paint_cost()
    labor_chrg()
    tot_cost()
```

All functions called

```
def gallon(space):
    global final
    final = space / wall
    print('\n''The gallons of paint required for the ' +\
          'job is', format(final, '.1f'),'gallons''\n')

def labor():
    global job
    job = final * work
    print('The hours of labor required for this' +\
          ' job is', format(job, '.1f'),'hours''\n')

def paint_cost():
    ask = input('Would you like to use premier or generic paint? ')
    if ask == "premier":
        prem_cost = final * premier
        print('The cost of the paint will total up ' +\
              'to be', format(prem_cost, '.2f'),'dollars''\n')
        labor_chrg(prem_cost)
    else:
        gene_cost = final * generic
        print('The cost of the paint will total up ' +\
              'to be', format(gene_cost, '.2f'),'dollars''\n')
        labor_chrg(gene_cost)
```

Whether he/she wants premier or generic paint.

```
def labor_chrg(arg):
    paint_c = arg
    job = final * work
    l_charge = job * labor_c
    print('The charge of the labor done will total up ' +\
          'to be', format(l_charge, '.2f'),'dollars''\n')
    tot_cost(paint_c, labor_c)

def tot_cost(paint_c, labor_c):
    paint_c1 = paint_c
    labor_c1 = labor_c
    p_cost = final * paint_c1
    l_charge = job * labor_c1
    total = p_cost + l_charge
    print('The total cost of the project you requested ' +\
          'will be', format(total, '.2f'),'dollars''\n')
```

Finished calculating the total cost.

```
paint_job()
```

I am having a hard time trying to figure out why my args are not being passed to the params properly. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: What params are not being passed? You need to explain that. What did you input, what did you expect as output? What did it output actually?

Comment: look at the `paint job` definition. You are passing nothing in `labor_chrg()`

Comment: TypeError: labor_chrg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

Comment: that is what I get I changed the labor_c  variable to l_charge but it still says that Function labor_chrg is missing the required arguement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to input something into these functions:

```
labor_chrg()
tot_cost()
```